# Mysql - I have 3 unique tables, need a hint on getting the details with the count

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 3 tables which are interconnected and i want to select columns from two tables and counts from table 3. If anyone is aware on this, any hint would be appreciated.

Below is the sql i tried, but the count is getting repeated

`SELECT distinct  p.p_id, p.p_f6, p.p_l4,m.m_id, (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM ttokens t where t.pdetail_id = p.pdetail_id 
    ) AS token_count
FROM tparking p,ttokens t LEFT join ttokens_md m ON t.trefn_id = m.trefn_id 
WHERE t.pdetail_id = p.pdetail_id`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `JOIN` with subquery to get your count instead of `selcet` subquery.

```
SELECT  p.p_id, p.p_f6, p.p_l4,m.m_id,t.cnt
FROM tparking p
JOIN (
    SELECT pdetail_id,COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM ttokens
    GROUP BY pdetail_id
) t ON t.pdetail_id = p.pdetail_id
LEFT join ttokens_md m ON t.trefn_id = m.trefn_id
```

**Note**

I would use `JOIN` instead of `,` comma with `where` condition to connect two tables,`,` is an old style.